# Search array strings mid word for a search word

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, autocomplete

I have an input that currently autocompletes but only if you type in the start of the word. I want to be able to type any part of the word in and if the string in the array contains this at any point it will show up. I want to change the current code to do this.

**Here is my code:**

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
    /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
    closeAllLists();
    if (!val) {
      return false;
    }
    currentFocus = -1;
    /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    /*for each item in the array...*/
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
      if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        /*make the matching letters bold:*/
        b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
        b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
        /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
        /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
          /*close the list of autocompleted values,
          (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
          closeAllLists();
        });
        a.appendChild(b);
      }
    }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
      increase the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus++;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
      /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
      decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus--;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {
        /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

// US State example

let states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New", "Hampshire", "New", "Jersey", "New", "Mexico", "New", "York", "North", "Carolina", "", "North", "Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode", "Island", "South", "Carolina", "South", "Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West", "Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"];

autocomplete(document.querySelector('input'), states)
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter state" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
```

to

```
if (arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) !=-1) {
```

and

```
b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
```

to

```
var pos = arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()),
    str1 = arr[i].substring(pos,pos+val.length);
b.innerHTML = arr[i].replace(str1,'<strong>'+str1+'</strong>');
```

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
    /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
    closeAllLists();
    if (!val) {
      return false;
    }
    currentFocus = -1;
    /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    /*for each item in the array...*/
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
      if (arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) !=-1) {
        /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        /*make the matching letters bold:*/
        var pos = arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()),
          str1 = arr[i].substring(pos,pos+val.length);
        b.innerHTML = arr[i].replace(str1,'<strong>'+str1+'</strong>');
        /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
        /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
          /*close the list of autocompleted values,
          (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
          closeAllLists();
        });
        a.appendChild(b);
      }
    }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
      increase the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus++;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
      /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
      decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus--;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {
        /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

// US State example

let states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New", "Hampshire", "New", "Jersey", "New", "Mexico", "New", "York", "North", "Carolina", "", "North", "Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode", "Island", "South", "Carolina", "South", "Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West", "Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"];

autocomplete(document.querySelector('input'), states)
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter state" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit too much going on in your code so I created a small example on how you can match words where the input appears anywhere in the string. I hope it is clear and that you can translate this to your own situation.

```js
const
  autoCompleteValues = [
    'Apple',
    'Banana',
    'Grape',
    'Orange',
    'Peach',
    'Raspberry',
    'Strawberry'
  ],
  input = document.getElementById('myInput'),
  list = document.getElementById('suggestions');
  
function onInputHandler(event) {
  // Get the current value of the input.
  const
    text = event.target.value;
  // When the input is empty, clear the suggestions list.
  if (text === '') {
    list.innerHTML = '';
    
    return;
  }
  
  const
    // Create a regex for the input text. The 'i' flag is to have the regex match the
    // input text regardless of casing (so 'test' matches 'TeSt').
    regex = new RegExp(text, 'i');
    // Create an array with the auto complete suggestions that match the user input.
    matches = autoCompleteValues.filter(value => regex.test(value));
    // Convert the array with matches to a string with an li per match.
    matchesHTML = matches.reduce((html, match) => html + `<li>${match}</li>`, '');
  // Update the list with autocomplete suggestions.  
  list.innerHTML = matchesHTML;
}
    
// React on changes to the value of the input element.
input.addEventListener('input', onInputHandler);
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..."/>
<ul id="suggestions">
</ul>
```